# SAP HANA IN Operator for a Concatenate Column

Tags: sql, hana

I have set up my table like so.

Table design

```
COLUMN_1  VARCHAR 100 PRIMARY KEY 
COLUMN_2 VARCHAR 100
```

Table entries

```
COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 
Test     | 104312
```

Why doesn't this query return a value when the value exists in the table?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [TABLE]
WHERE   ( CONCAT([COLUMN_1], [COLUMN_2]) = 'Test104312' );
```

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT(col1,col2) FROM TABLE` returns `Test104312` ?

Comment: is there any space_? so you need trim ?

Answer (score 2):

> Use NVARCHAR

The solution is to alter the table design to use NVARCHAR(100) instead of VARCHAR(100).

The NVARCHAR type will not pad values with white-space and there are other benefits as well.

Table design

```
COLUMN_1 NVARCHAR 100 PRIMARY KEY 
COLUMN_2 NVARCHAR 100
```

Further reading:

- NVARCHAR https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186939.aspx
- VARCHAR https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for MS SQL.

```
            DECLARE @table TABLE (COLUMN_1 varchar(11), COLUMN_2 varchar(10))
            INSERT @table VALUES ('Test','104312')

            select *,concat(COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2) from @table
            WHERE(concat(COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2) = 'Test104312');
```

Output :

```
COLUMN_1    COLUMN_2    (No column name)
Test        104312      Test104312
```

Comment: this is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

May be there is something extra space issue in table data so you can try by using TRM in the following way :

```
WHERE(concat(TRIM(COLUMN_1),TRIM(COLUMN_2)) = 'Test104312')
```

Answer (score 0):

The query does not return a value, because the value does NOT exist in your table. 
Maybe your table contains something that looks identical, but contains spaces or other non-printable characters. And it has nothing to do with VARCHAR(100) and NVARCHAR(100) in HANA afaik. VARCHAR(100) can contain 100 ASCII Characters, and 100 or less Unicode Characters, depending on how many two- or more-byte UTF8 Characters are included in the string. NVARCHAR(100) can alway contain 100 Unicode Characters. Here an example:

```
create column table "TABLE" 
( COLUMN_1  NVARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
  COLUMN_2 NVARCHAR(100) );
Insert into "TABLE" (Column_1, Column_2) values ('Test', '104312'); -- will be found
Insert into "TABLE" (Column_1, Column_2) values ('Test ', '104312'); --will not be found, space
Insert into "TABLE" (Column_1, Column_2) values ('Test'  || nchar(13), '104312' ); --will not be found, non-printable

Select * from "TABLE"; -- will list all three entries
```

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM    "TABLE" --will list only the first entry
  WHERE   ( CONCAT("COLUMN_1", "COLUMN_2") = 'Test104312' );
```

[image]

Also, the syntax you use for quoting identifieres using brackets does not work in HANA (or there is some feature I do not know), brackets can be used in MS-SQL. The examlpe works in both, row and column store. A trick to spot non-printable characters is to cut the result from HANA Studio and past it to notepad++.